# Get real primary screen in c# with a multi monitor setup?

Tags: c#, winforms, screen

I have a c# windows application that work with multimonitors. The application has  a main form that must be showed in the primary display and a full screen form that needs to be displayed on the second screen (this second form is showed in a 3d goggles). 
This is my way to assign the screens:
`Screen.AllScreens[0]` for first screen and `Screen.AllScreens[1]` for secondary screen but i'm having problems with a new version of the 3d goggles because this are HDMI and even if i set the main screen to the monitor (DVI), the goggles are set as screen 1.

Could be a better way to use `Screen.AllScreens[0].Bounds.X == 0` as a way to check if the screen 0 is the primary screen?

Update: I used before `Screen.AllScreens[x]` the property `Screen.PrimaryScreen` but that property also give me troubles with some monitor-goggles configuration that i really don't remember them.

Answer (score 4):

Note that in Windows, it is possible to move the primary/secondary display to any position (I spent several years with my secondary monitor on top of the primary) and thus checking for bounds would be useless.

Instead, note that the `Screen` class has a [`Primary` Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.primary(v=vs.110).aspx) to check whether a given screen is primary. You could thus

```
secondaryScreen = Screen.AllScreens
    .Where(s => s.Primary == false)
    .Single(); // Note: this will throw an exception if there isn't a secondary screen, or more than one.
```

... or the [`PrimaryScreen` static Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.primaryscreen(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the primary `Screen` directly.

Comment: The first thing you say will not be happening because it's a requirement of the equipment to set the screens one right to the other. The `Primary` and `PrimaryScreen` classes how they take the "primary" screen? because in the microsoft notes doesn't say anything about how they take them.

Comment: Those aren't classes, they're properties - the first is accessible on objects of type `Screen` and the second using the class `Screen` the exactsame wya you're pulling up `AllScreens`.

As for the above code, I'm saying to check because I'm making assumptions for the windows shell, not your particular hardware ;3

Comment: I know... but i remember some time before that i use this properties before i start to use `Screen.AllScreens[x]` and i don't remember why those properties gave me problems too (sorry for my bad english).

Comment: If those properties aren't working properly, that would be a good reason to isolate the expected/actual behaviour and post another question - or update this one

Comment: Although it is possible to set any screen as primary screen, I think the definition of the primary screen is that it contains (0,0). If you have acreen left of the primary screen, it has negative coordinates. So both methods should work. But I cannot find a reference for that, so I would stick with Screen.Primary

Comment: Note that the Linq can be simplified to `Screen.AllScreens.Single(s => !s.Primary);`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen while true, I decided to the use a `Where` followed by a `Single` to make the last line more easily changed